# partitioning my laptop to dual boot Win7 & Debian

Tags: windows-7, debian, multi-boot, thinkpad

I just got a new laptop and want to add Debian to the already installed Windows 7.  It came with 2 primary partitions, one for restore and one for Windows 7.

I shrunk the Windows 7 partition down to 60 GB.

Now I'd like to have the following additional partitions:

```
/boot (ext 4, 200 MG)
/    (ext4, 30 GB)
swap (4 GB)
```

and then the remaining space, ~150G, be a ntfs partition for data that can be shared between the 2 OSes.

But since I can only have 4 primary partitions, I'm running into problems. 
I've been reading about primary and logical partitions but my grasp is light.
And it seems that the /boot and swap partitions are required to be Primary partitions. (I know I can put / and /boot on the same partition but thats still too many.)

Can someone give me some guidance/suggestions on how best to partition my drive?

I don't know if this info is helpful, but the laptop is a Thinkpad T400 with 250 G HD and 2 G of ram (new = new to me) and I've been trying to install Debian with the thumbdrive and unetbootin.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do without swap (if it is a recent computer you probably can), you could make the two remaining partitions into:

- a `/boot` partition for debian
- and an extended partition, under which you could have
        -  `/`
        -  your extra ntfs partition
       -  theoretically others in the future.

Even if you do want swap, you could always create a swap *file* later.

Comment: I thought swap was required?

Comment: I see, I'm reading up on that now.  Not sure, the laptop is a 2008 with 2 G of RAM (though I expect to get more as soon as I can that will be at least a few weeks)

Comment: That's plenty unless you're doing video editing or some other high-performance task. Even if, a swapfile is an option.

Answer (score 0):

No, Linux does not require primary partitions for anything.

Make an Extended partition and sub-divide into Logical partitions however many you need.